# Issues Migrating Ejb 2.0 from jboss 4 to jboss 5.1

Tags: jboss5.x

Deploying an EAR application in jboss 5.1 throws an error.
Below is the error

> The content of element type "message-driven" must match "(description?,display-name?,small-
>    icon?,large-icon?,ejb-name,ejb-class,transaction-type,message-selector?,acknowledge-
>    mode?,message-driven-destination?,env-entry*,ejb-ref*,ejb-local-ref*,security-identity?,resource-
>    ref*,resource-env-ref*)".

This EAR application worked in JBoss 4.0.2, but not working on Jboss 5.1

Thanks
Ravi S

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely the schema your `ejb-jar.xml` is pointing to. Are you pointing to version [3](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd) or [2.1](http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd)? Try removing the line that specifies the schema is you are pointing to the correct schema and its still not working.

Comment: No acctually we were in circular dependency